# How to remove rows with any zero value

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, zero

I have a problem to solve how to remove rows with a Zero value in R. In others hand, I can use `na.omit()` to delete all the NA values or use `complete.cases()` to delete rows that contains NA values.

Is there anyone know how to remove rows with a Zero Values in R?

For example :

***Before***

```
|    DateTime      | Mac1  | Mac2  | Mac3  | Mac4  |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2011-04-02 06:00 | 20    | 0     | 20    | 20    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:05 | 21    | 21    | 21    | 21    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:10 | 22    | 22    | 22    | 22    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:15 | 23    | 23    | 0     | 23    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:20 | 24    | 24    | 24    | 24    | 
| 2011-04-02 06:25 | 0     | 25    | 25    | 0     |
```

***After***

```
|    DateTime      | Mac1  | Mac2  | Mac3  | Mac4  |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2011-04-02 06:05 | 21    | 21    | 21    | 21    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:10 | 22    | 22    | 22    | 22    |  
| 2011-04-02 06:20 | 24    | 24    | 24    | 24    |
```

Comment: One route: reduce this to a problem you've already solved by replacing the zeros with NAs.

Comment: Thanks Joran, for your reply.. But, i dont understand, what mean of replacing the zeros with NAs? Because before i get the table i have deleted NAs values before. But there is still 0's values.
Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Ok i think i must use this code to replace 0 with NAs.. 
`data[which(data==0)] = NA`

Comment: @YougyZ I think instead you need `data[which(data==0)] = NA_character_`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are a few different ways of doing this. I prefer using `apply`, since it's easily extendable:

```
##Generate some data
dd = data.frame(a = 1:4, b= 1:0, c=0:3)

##Go through each row and determine if a value is zero
row_sub = apply(dd, 1, function(row) all(row !=0 ))
##Subset as usual
dd[row_sub,]
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use filter from dplyr package.

Let's call your data frame df

`library(dplyr)
df1 <- filter(df, Mac1 > 0, Mac2 > 0, Mac3 > 0, Mac4 > 0)`

df1 will have only rows with entries above zero. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

I would do the following.

Set the zero to NA.

```
 data[data==0] <- NA
 data
```

Delete the rows associated with NA.

```
 data2<-data[complete.cases(data),]
```

Answer (score 8):

I would probably go with Joran's suggestion of replacing 0's with NAs and then using the built in functions you mentioned. If you can't/don't want to do that, one approach is to use `any()` to find rows that contain 0's and subset those out:

```
set.seed(42)
#Fake data
x <- data.frame(a = sample(0:2, 5, TRUE), b = sample(0:2, 5, TRUE))
> x
  a b
1 2 1
2 2 2
3 0 0
4 2 1
5 1 2
#Subset out any rows with a 0 in them
#Note the negation with ! around the apply function
x[!(apply(x, 1, function(y) any(y == 0))),]
  a b
1 2 1
2 2 2
4 2 1
5 1 2
```

To implement Joran's method, something like this should get you started:

```
x[x==0] <- NA
```

Comment: thanks anyway, but i have done it with csgillespie solution.. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could swap your `0`'s for `NA` and then use one of those solutions, but for sake of a difference, you could notice that a number will only have a finite logarithm if it is greater than `0`, so that `rowSums` of the `log` will only be finite if there are no zeros in a row.

```
dfr[is.finite(rowSums(log(dfr[-1]))),]
```

Comment: +1 for clever, but I would certainly prefer an `all`/`any` solution in practice ...

Answer (score 5):

I prefer a simple adaptation of csgillespie's method, foregoing the need of a function definition:

```
d[apply(d!=0, 1, all),]
```

where `d` is your data frame.

Comment: This does not work for me, but this works: d[!apply(d==0, 1, all),]

Answer (score 5):

Using tidyverse/dplyr, you can also remove rows with any zero value in a subset of variables:

```
# variables starting with Mac must be non-zero
filter_at(df, vars(starts_with("Mac")), all_vars((.) != 0))

# variables x, y, and z must be non-zero
filter_at(df, vars(x, y, z), all_vars((.) != 0))

# all numeric variables must be non-zero
filter_if(df, is.numeric, all_vars((.) != 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

As dplyr 1.0.0 deprecated the scoped variants which @Feng Mai nicely showed, here is an update with the new syntax. This might be useful because in this case, `across()` doesn't work, and it took me some time to figure out the solution as follows.

The goal was to extract all rows that contain at least one 0 in a column.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across(everything(.)) == 0))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0
2     2     0     1
3     4     0     3
4     0     0     0
```

with the data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b= 1:0, c=0:3)
df <- rbind(df, c(0,0,0))
df <- rbind(df, c(9,9,9))
```

So it correctly doesn't return the last row containing all 9s.

Answer (score 2):

i have tried many ways but in my experience, i choose to set the zero to NA then remove the rows associated with NA by using complete.cases.

```
dt[dt==0] <- NA
dt_<-dt[complete.cases(dt),]
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can select the columns which we want to test using `grep`, compare the data with 0, use `rowSums` to select rows which has all non-zero values.

```
cols <- grep("^Mac", names(df))
df[rowSums(df[cols] != 0) == length(cols), ]

#          DateTime Mac1 Mac2 Mac3 Mac4
#1 2011-04-02 06:05   21   21   21   21
#2 2011-04-02 06:10   22   22   22   22
#3 2011-04-02 06:20   24   24   24   24
```

Doing this with inverted logic but giving the same output

```
df[rowSums(df[cols] == 0) == 0, ]
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can use `filter_at` to test for specific columns and use `all_vars` to select rows where all the values are not equal to 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Mac")), all_vars(. != 0))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2011-04-02 06:00", 
"2011-04-02 06:05", "2011-04-02 06:10", "2011-04-02 06:15", "2011-04-02 06:20", 
"2011-04-02 06:25"), class = "factor"), Mac1 = c(20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 0L), Mac2 = c(0L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L), Mac3 = c(20L, 
21L, 22L, 0L, 24L, 25L), Mac4 = c(20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more up-to-date approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_any(starts_with("Mac"), ~ . == 0))

          DateTime Mac1 Mac2 Mac3 Mac4
1 2011-04-02 06:05   21   21   21   21
2 2011-04-02 06:10   22   22   22   22
3 2011-04-02 06:20   24   24   24   24
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer possible would benefit from implicit coercion of numeric to logical, with which zeroes are converted to FALSE and other values to TRUE, and using `if_any/if_all`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(if_all(starts_with('Mac')))
```

Comment: Long time no see my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my head on a similar problem, I came up with this:

I wanted to leave the zeros in column 1 and 9 because they made sense there but leave the zeros out from the rest of the columns. This code would produce bigger than zero values in column 2 till 8 in the data frame, leaving column 1 and 9 intact.

```
dataset %>% filter(data.frame(dataset[,2:8]>0))
```