# R - Resize a 3D array by removing all-zeros 2D matrices of the x, y, and z dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, r, matlab, lua

Is there any function in R, Python, Lua, Java, Matlab or any programming language that can reduce the size of the 3D input_array from c(6, 6, 6) to c(4, 4, 4) by deleting all-zero matrices on the periphery of the 3 dimensions?

```
## Create an empty array with all zeros
input_array <- array(data = c(0), dim = c(6, 6, 6)) 

## Populate the central locations of the array with 1
input_array[, ,2:5] <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,  
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                nrow = 6, ncol = 6) 

## Show the input_array
input_array 

## The target output
output_array <- array(data = c(1), dim = c(4, 4, 4))
```

So, in other words, I am looking for a function that takes the input_array as an input and spits the output_array as an output. I want to maintain the 3D nature of the array throughout the conversion. The reason I am looking into this, is that I have very large 3D arrays with lots of zeros around the periphery and by removing all-zeros matrices out of the three dimensions, I can achieve considerable reduction in the sizes of these arrays and hence allow for more efficient processing.

In case there is no function out there, what could be a logic to write a new function so as to get this done? Use whatever language you prefer if you have anything to share, any feedback or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it supposed to shave off surfaces based on whether they are all zero (if  so: repeatedly?) or just one from each side?

Comment: repeatedly as long as the surface is all-zeros, this could be one surface or more than one.

Comment: Pick a language. Still working on a more elegant way in R, but functional: `input_array[apply(input_array, 1, function(x){any(x != 0)}), apply(input_array, 2, function(x){any(x != 0)}), apply(input_array, 3, function(x){any(x != 0)})]`

Comment: @alistaire - you can shrink it up a bit by working on logical vectors - `input_array[,,apply(input_array!=0, 3, any)]` for instance.

Comment: Also worth linking for future searchers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375664/remove-layer-of-array-that-contains-all-zeros/25375698

Comment: Nice! Less repetitive, though pretty much the same computations still: `abind::asub(input_array, lapply(1:3, function(d){apply(input_array != 0, d, any)}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do reasonably well in R with the help of the `abind` package, which is handy for dealing with arrays:

```
abind::asub(input_array,    # take this and subset
            lapply(1:3, function(d){    # iterate over its dimensions
                apply(input_array != 0, d, any)    # look for any non-zero elements
            }))
## , , 1
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1    1    1    1
## [3,]    1    1    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    1    1
## 
## , , 2
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1    1    1    1
## [3,]    1    1    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    1    1
## 
## , , 3
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1    1    1    1
## [3,]    1    1    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    1    1
## 
## , , 4
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1    1    1    1
## [3,]    1    1    1    1
## [4,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, it runs fine one the given example.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all of those who shared their thoughts or cited other similar posts. I reached this through your answers:

```
## Create an empty array with all zeros
input_array <- array(data = c(0), dim = c(6, 6, 6)) 

## Populate the central locations of the array with 1
input_array[, ,2:5] <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,  
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                nrow = 6, ncol = 6) 

## Show the input_array
input_array 

## The target output
(output_array <- input_array[apply(input_array != 0, 3, any),
                             apply(input_array != 0, 2, any),
                             apply(input_array != 0, 1, any)])
```

I haven't tested it with different inputs, so further testing for different inputs may need to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option (`python`/`numpy`):

```
xcrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(0,1)))[0]
ycrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(0,2)))[0]
zcrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(1,2)))[0]
output = input[zcrit[0]:zcrit[-1]+1,ycrit[0]:ycrit[-1]+1,xcrit[0]:xcrit[-1]+1]
```

explanation `np.any` returns True if along the dimensions passed at least one cell is True. it returns a boolean array shaped like the remaining dimensions

`np.where` finds the indices of the True cells of its argument.
in this example we use it to find the indices of the first and last not-all-zero slice along each coordinate

Sample run:

```
>>> input = np.zeros((6,6,6))
>>> input[1:-2,1:-2,2:-1] = 1
>>> xcrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(0,1)))[0]
>>> ycrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(0,2)))[0]
>>> zcrit = np.where(np.any(input, axis=(1,2)))[0]
>>> output = input[zcrit[0]:zcrit[-1]+1,ycrit[0]:ycrit[-1]+1,xcrit[0]:xcrit[-1]+1]
>>> # verify
... input.sum(), output.sum(), output.size
(27.0, 27.0, 27)
```